# Canonoid transformation that is NOT canonical

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

Canonoid transformations are defined [here](https://books.google.es/books?id=Eql9dRQDgvQC&pg=PA233&lpg=PA233&dq=canonoid%20transformations%20hamiltonian&source=bl&ots=cq6OcTyUi2&sig=ACfU3U256fpkcoFv5L4bIK4g0JfUDnQIWw&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwim4sWq9YLmAhWU5OAKHZqgBWgQ6AEwCXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=canonoid%20&f=false) as preserving the hamiltonian structure of the dynamical system for a particular hamiltonian, but not necessariy for every hamiltonian, in such a way that a transformation is canonical iff it is canonoid for every hamiltonian (also explained in the above reference).

I am wondering if there would be a somewhat systematic way to search for canonoid transformations that are **not** canonical. 
In particular, I am interested i finding a canonoid but not canonical transformation fo the hamiltonian:

$$H(x_i,p_i)=\frac{1}{2m}p^ip_i+\frac{a}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}-b\sqrt{p^ip_i}\sqrt{x^ix_i}$$

Comment: Have you tried writing down the differential equation that the transformation needs to fulfill? It should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: I am afraid I dont know which equation that would be

Comment: One idea is to limit oneself to time-independent canonoid transformations with $K=H$, but it is still not an easy problem.